# How to pass multiple variables and functions to chroot envrionment?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, chroot

I am writing a script to automate my Arch Linux installation process and I've bumped into an environmental problem. I have a file with the installation sequence and a file that holds all the functions, sourced in the beginning of the script.

Running `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c someFunction` does not recognize the function nor the variables set before this line of code.

If I `export -f someFunction` it will recognize the function, but `someFunction` in itself is just a decomposition function, which only calls other functions. What is the most elegant way to source all the functions inside the chroot environment?

I also need a way of exporting all variables, set by the user at the beginning of the script, into the chrooted environment.(I'm guessing solving the above will also solve this problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to pass my variables without copying them over ( would present a security risk to copy sensitive variables outside the script ). Below is a snippet.

```
cp archsin-functions /mnt/root/;

arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash -- << EOCHROOT

    source \$HOME/archsin-functions;

    createSwap;
    setLocale "${CITY}";
    setHost "${HSTNAME}";
    setInitramfs "${REPOAPITOKEN}" "${REPOID}";
    setUser "${USRGROUPS}" "${USRNAME}" "${USRPASSWD}" "${REPOAPITOKEN}" "${REPOID}";

    systemctl enable NetworkManager.service

EOCHROOT

shred --verbose -u --zero --iterations=3 /mnt/root/archsin-functions;
```

`<< EOCHRROOT` - [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) pases the lines up to `EOCHROOT` marker to the `/bin/bash` execution shell created in the chroot env.

Since variable expansion is done when the file is read the functions will be served the data held inside the variables correctly.
The escaped `$` prevents expansion of `$HOME` until the line is actually executed. When it is executed it will be done inside the chroot environment making `$HOME` evaluate to the `/root` folder of the chroot env where the functions file has been placed.
After execution the file will be removed without a trace.

Answer (score 0):

Put the variables and functions in a file in the `/etc/profile.d` directory in the chroot hierarchy, and bash *should* source that upon startup (if you've set up the other /etc files bash uses).